# Haddop MRUnit MapDriver.addInput() giving NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer error

Tags: hadoop, serialization, mapreduce, bytebuffer, mrunit

I am using MRunit to unit test our MapReducer below are pom changes

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.mrunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>mrunit</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
    <classifier>hadoop1</classifier>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

I am not using AVRO.

I have added below lines to get rid of serialization issue

```
Configuration conf = driver.getConfiguration();
conf.set("io.serializations", "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization,"
            + "org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.WritableSerialization");
```

Now, I am using below api to add inputs

```
MapDriver.addInput(Map<String, ByteBuffer> key, Map<String, ByteBuffer> val)
```

But now when I am adding my inputs with above call, I am getting below error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:86)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:97)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copyWithConf(Serialization.java:110)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.copy(TestDriver.java:675)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.TestDriver.copyPair(TestDriver.java:679)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.MapDriverBase.addInput(MapDriverBase.java:120)
at com.pearson.psn.mapreduce.EventMapperTest.testMapper(EventMapperTest.java:102)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:73)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:46)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:180)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:41)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:173)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: java.nio.HeapByteBuffer
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1164)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1001)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:940)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1469)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1400)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1158)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:330)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization$JavaSerializationSerializer.serialize(JavaSerialization.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.serializer.JavaSerialization$JavaSerializationSerializer.serialize(JavaSerialization.java:65)
at org.apache.hadoop.mrunit.internal.io.Serialization.copy(Serialization.java:80)
... 30 more
```

Any idea what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is caused probably by trying to serialise ByteBuffers. They are not serialisable and you need to convert them to arrays of bytes.